# Mid rule actions bison - what is the meaning $n in mid rule?

Tags: parsing, bison

In given:

```
Var:   Art { if( $1 == NULL) print("error"); } Asta
Art:   /*epsilon*/
Asta:  /*epsilon*/
```

What is the meaning of `$1` in line number one (the line of `Var: ...`).
Because the mid-rule action, I not sure if $1 is meaning to the not-terminal `Art` or not.

Comment: Instead of relying on comments (which might be wrong or missing), you should use [%empty](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Empty-Rules.html).

Answer (score 2):

This is explained in  more detail in the [bison manual section on Midrule actions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Midrule-Action-Translation.html).

Yes, in your example `$1` refers to the value of the terminal `Art`.